# Unable to trigger specific collapse with radio button using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-blade

Good day, I am using laravel blade to dynamically generate some radio buttons and forms depending on user selections. So the user will select a certain amount of jobs and then forms will be generated for the number of jobs. These forms will be hidden and only revealed(via bootstrap collapse) only if a certain radio button is checked. However, what happens is when I check a radio button from one group of radio buttons, all forms are shown. Can anyone assist me?

I am using jquery to show/hide the collapse depending on what radio button is checked. I have tried assigning individual IDs to the buttons dynamically using loop properties. Still having the error.

Blade file (RADIO BUTTON SECTION)

```
    @foreach($interest as $job)
     @if($job != 0)
     <!-- EXPERIENCE RADIO BUTTON-->
      <label></label>
      <label>Experience for {{$jobs[$loop->index]}} </label>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="noxp{{$loop->iteration}}" name="jbxp{{$loop->iteration}}"  value="0">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="noxp{{$loop->iteration}}">No Experience</label>
      </div>


      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="xp1{{$loop->iteration}}" name="jbxp{{$loop->iteration}}" value="1">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="xp1{{$loop->iteration}}">1-11 Months</label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="xp2{{$loop->iteration}}" name="jbxp{{$loop->iteration}}" value="2">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="xp2{{$loop->iteration}}">1-5 Years</label>
      </div> 

      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="xp3{{$loop->iteration}}" name="jbxp{{$loop->iteration}}" value="3">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="xp3{{$loop->iteration}}">5+ Years</label>
      </div>
```

Blade file (FORM SECTION)

```
     <form id="ref-form-{{$loop->iteration}}" class="form-horizontal" action="{{url('/send-refs')}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
              <div class="row">
                <div class="collapse panel-collapse collapse" id="panel-{{$loop->iteration}}">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <!--REF-1-DETAILS-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
                          <label>Last Place Work As {{$jobs[$loop->index]}}</label>
                          <input type="text" name="PlaceWorked" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last place worked" value=" " required>

                        </div>
                      </div>
     </form>
```

JQuery being used to show/hide collapse:

```
       <script>
      $(".custom-control-input").click(function() {

      $("#ref-form-1 :input").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#ref-form-2 :input").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#ref-form-3 :input").attr("disabled", false);

      if ($("input[name=jbxp1]:checked").val() == "0") {
          $("#ref-form-1 :input").attr("disabled", true);
          $('#panel-1').collapse('hide');

      }

      if($("input[name=jbxp1]:checked").val() != "0") {
        $(' #panel-1').collapse('show');
      }


      if ($("input[name=jbxp2]:checked").val() == "0") {
          $("#ref-form-2 :input").attr("disabled", true);
          $('#panel-2').collapse('hide');
      }
      if($("input[name=jbxp2]:checked").val() != "0") {
        $('#panel-2').collapse('show');
      }

      if ($("input[name=jbxp3]:checked").val() == "0") {
          $("#ref-form-3 :input").attr("disabled", true);
          $(' #panel-3').collapse('hide');
      }
      if($("input[name=jbxp3]:checked").val() != "0") {
        $('#panel-3').collapse('show');
      }
  });
    </script>
```

So, I'm expecting that if a radio button is clicked from the first group, the corresponding action will reflect only on the first form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hide` function with a duration if you want to. See the jQuery documentation for all the possible options.

```
$('#panel-3').hide();
```

Comment: no this doesn't do it. now when i click, nothing happens.

Comment: the radio buttons seem to be referring to the same form but I can't figure out why

Comment: @kish77 Can you provide the outputted html of the radio buttons and the forms?

Comment: Do you mean an image? There is no output to gain. In the code above the for loop will generate the radio buttons and the form